# Java AtomicInteger getAndIncrement() and compareAndSet

Tags: java, multithreading, nonblocking, compare-and-swap

I am trying to understand how the `current` in getAndIncrement is updated, here is that piece of code.

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

I understand that compareAndSet will compare whether the current value is same as the value stored in register, if is it same then update the value in register with next.

The part I don't understand is that why doesn't it return `next` instead of `current`.

When enter the loop, `current` is set as an int and `current` is not a reference value, so if current is initialized as 5, then when it returns current, should it be 5 as well? Or when it returns `current`, the `current` will called `get()` again to get the updated value from register?

Comment: because you call [`getAndIncrement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement--), which somewhat resembles the postincrement operator (`i++`). For the behaviour you describe, there is [`incrementAndGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--), which resembles the preincrement operator (`++i`).

Comment: What I am asking is how "current" is updated as a primitive, I only see the value that "current" refers to is updated ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. Java is pass-by-value, so `current` will never be changed and thus in your given example `5` will be returned. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ah, I got you, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's to improve concurrency.

If it returned `next`, the method would have to have synchronised code, otherwise another thread could modify the value between setting it and returning it.

By not returning `next`, only the actual modification needs synchronising, putting the responsibility, and optimization, of synchronization in one place; the `compareAndSet()`. When synchronization is shared between methods, it's much more complicated to coordinate safe state changes.

Comment: but current is not a reference but a primitive value, does current calls get() again at the execution of return? Here I can only see the value current "referenced" to is updated.

Comment: One could argue that only one thread is able to return a specific value, if `next` is returned without synchronization (and overflows asied), since only one thread will be able to successfully call the CAS-operation and therefore return a specific value. The `next` value may not return the actual current value, but this is possibly not wanted.